# How to implement a zoomable drawing-area?

Tags: java, swing

**Situation:** I have implemented a Java Swing application, that screenshots a selected component in an existing program and displays it in a new frame. Once displayed you can draw rectangles, circles and spawn textboxes.

My program consists of a drawing-component located within a frame that is drawn on via. the *`paintComponent()`* method. More specifically I draw two Buffered images, one for the image itself and the other one on top that stores the drawings.

```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Scale
        int newWidth = (int) (image.getWidth(null) * zoom);
        int newHeight = (int) (image.getHeight(null) * zoom);

        // Display image and drawing
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
        g.drawImage(drawImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight, null);
    }
```

The shapes themself are drawn on the **drawImage** seen above. To draw on the image I use the drawer variable: `drawer = (Graphics2D) drawImage.getGraphics();`

```
private void drawRectangle(boolean fill, Point scaledNow) {
        if (fill) {
            drawer.fillRect(
                    // X-coordinate
                    (int) (Math.min(scaledNow.getX(), lastClick.getX())),
                    // Y-coordinate
                    (int) (Math.min(scaledNow.getY(), lastClick.getY())),
                    // width
                    (int) (Math.abs(scaledNow.getX() - lastClick.getX())),
                    // height
                    (int) (Math.abs(scaledNow.getY() - lastClick.getY())));
        }
        else {
            drawer.drawRect(
                    // X-coordinate
                    (int) Math.min(scaledNow.getX(), lastClick.getX()),
                    // Y-coordinate
                    (int) Math.min(scaledNow.getY() , lastClick.getY()),
                    // width
                    (int) Math.abs(scaledNow.getX() - lastClick.getX()),
                    // height
                    (int) Math.abs(scaledNow.getY() - lastClick.getY()));
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** I'm trying to implement an undo-button, that deletes the latest shape based on this example. [Undo example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701314/12271277)

In order to draw directly on the component I would have to do all the scaling myself as far as I know but when I keep my current approach the method mentioned in the Undo example doesn't work.

**How should I handle drawing on an image that itself is drawn?**

Comment: You don't draw directly on the component.  You save what the user wants as a logical java.awt.Rectangle, a logical circle, or a logical text box.  You then draw on the component from the logical model.  Deleting an element from the logical model deletes the element from the drawing.  As far as zooming, you maintain one image at full scale and create a second image at a reduced scale.

Comment: If you need undo functionality the don't draw on a BufferedImage. An easier approach is to use a ArrayList that contains the objects you want to draw and then just iterate through the ArrayList in the paintComponent() method. Then for undo you just remove the last object added to the ArrayList and repaint the component. Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this approach.

Comment: Also, you can use the `Graphics2D.getTransform().scale` method to do the scaling for you.